# changing tab space in atom-typescript

Tags: javascript, indentation, atom-editor

Atom-typescript changes tab space from 2 to 4 when we format the code.

I changed formatting.js file and set it to 2 but still i'm facing the same issue..

How can i change the tab space in atom-typescript?

below is the content of formatting.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
/**
 * Maintainance:
 * When a new option is added add it to:
 * - the FormatCodeOptions interface
 * - the defaultFormatCodeOptions function
 * - the makeFormatCodeOptions function
 */
const os_1 = require("os");
function defaultFormatCodeOptions() {
    return {
        baseIndentSize: 2,
        indentSize: 2,
        tabSize: 2,
        newLineCharacter: os_1.EOL,
        convertTabsToSpaces: true,
        indentStyle: "Smart",
        insertSpaceAfterCommaDelimiter: true,
        insertSpaceAfterSemicolonInForStatements: true,
        insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators: true,
        insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements: true,
        insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions: false,
        insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis: false,
        insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets: false,
        insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces: false,
        insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces: false,
        placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions: false,
        placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks: false,
    };
}
exports.defaultFormatCodeOptions = defaultFormatCodeOptions;
//# sourceMappingURL=formatting.js.map
```

Comment: Have you checked in the Editor settings?

Comment: yes, editor tab length is set to 2.
Atom -> preferences -> editor ->Tab Length

Comment: when i format the code using atom-typescript, it changes tab spaces from 2 to 4.

Comment: Maybe this would be a good reference: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1236

Comment: yeah, this worked !! I'm posting changes that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @baruch, here is the reference: [github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1236](http://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1236)

I'm posting what worked for me.

To change indentation to 2 for `atom-typescript`:

1. Go to your project directory.
2. Open or create `tsconfig.json`.
3. Add the following code

   ```
   "formatCodeOptions": {
       "baseIndentSize": 0,
       "indentSize": 2,
       "tabSize": 2,
       "newLineCharacter": "\n",
       "convertTabsToSpaces": true,
       "indentStyle": "Smart",
       "insertSpaceAfterCommaDelimiter": true,
       "insertSpaceAfterSemicolonInForStatements": false,
       "insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators": true,
       "insertSpaceAfterConstructor": false,
       "insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": true,
       "insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false,
       "insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis": false,
       "insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": false,
       "insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
       "insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": false,
       "insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": false,
       "insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": false,
       "placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false,
       "placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false
   }
   ```

This worked for me!